# Bug in voting system

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I can do 2 up-votes on one answer by doing the following:

Up vote

Down vote - tells me "Vote down requires 100 reputation", lowers score by 2, then raises it again

Up vote

This leaves the final score for the answer 2 higher than when I started. I have only tested this on superuser, as I don't have enough reputation for up votes on other sites.

Comment: Do both upvotes "stick" when you refresh the page?

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't, it goes back to having added 1. Whoops

Comment: +1: Even if it's only a display bug it's still a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on Server Fault by casting 2 downvotes to bring my reputation to 99, then testing on a random question.

The test question I picked had 1 score. After 1 upvote, it was at 2. Doing the trick, I can make it display 3. However, if I try to reverse the upvote by casting a downvote again, it drops back to 1, then resets itself to 2 because I can't cast the downvote. Additionally, if I still go back and try to upvote it to 3, a page refresh will show only a score of 2.

So internally, it is properly tracked. It's a display bug rather than a bug with the voting system itself, much like certain other reported bugs about the arrows disappearing when they shouldn't because of a popup. And as a display bug, it's minor and extremely rare. I don't think it's anything to worry about.